# How to draw route from OSRM on right road using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, route

[Asking to OSRM](https://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=43.5289225,-5.658941400000001&loc=43.52927193020045,-5.6613644560608405&instructions=true&z=5&alt=false) for a route, OSRM is returning the geometry:

```
"route_geometry":"ity_rArqlxIvTv|AoCrY"
```

After [decode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility?csw=1) them, I'm getting 3 GPS coordinates:

```
43.529557,          -5.659434
43.529208999999994, -5.660934
43.529281,          -5.66136
```

But with just 3 points, I'm getting [this route](http://jsfiddle.net/abgcvqw3/36/) :(

[image]

How can I draw a right route on the road with openlayers? Like [this](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The route geometry you get is a encoded polyline. You can create a route from it as follows:

```
// route is ol.geom.LineString
var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
    factor: 1e6
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
var feature = new ol.Feature(route);
feature.setStyle(styles.route);
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
```

Source : http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/

Answer (score 3):

With Latest API use

**overview**
simplified (default), full, false   Add overview geometry either full, simplified according to highest zoom level it could be display on, or not at all.

curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/-1.8744130630953275,52.45318441573963;-1.879401971863028,52.451059431849615;-1.8783612747652496,52.44962092302177;-1.882395317123648,52.44969938835112;-1.8824275036318268,52.452046744809195;-1.8794663448793851,52.45332825709778;-1.8898840446932288,52.454230523991356**?overview=full**'

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add this parameter:
https://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?**z=18**&
Then, it will return so many points as the zoom (18 in this example) :)